I want to pick my flight route. I can either get 2 round trip tickets (SRC<->MID, MID<->DST) or 3rd party booking (SRC<->DST). Which is more reliable?
I want to fly from Source (SRC) to Destination (DST). They are far, and have no single airline servicing both airports. So, I was thinking that it would be a good opportunity for me to visit Middle (MID). I can see 2 ways of pulling this off.

Book a round trip ticket SRC<->MID from the airline flying. And book MID<->DST from the other airline flying. I will give myself about 2 days at MID both ways, so that if my flight is delayed/advanced by several hours, I'll still be able to catch my flight.
Use a 3rd party booking service (What I found was from trip.com , I don't know how good they are specifically, but a booking service like that) to get a ticket that includes SRC->MID, MID->DST, DST->MID and MID->SRC.

The recurring suggestion here is to never use 3rd party booking services, given that if anything goes wrong, they try to avoid all responsibility. Given my circumstance, what would you suggest?

The Travel.SE recurring suggestion is good advice. We would advise you to follow it, and for exactly the reason you state.

There are so many combinations of different airlines/airports and everything, in the current state of the question, apart from the basic suggestion of no 3rd party, we can't really help you farther

@NicolasFormichella "apart from the basic suggestion of no 3rd party, we can't really help you farther" That's exactly my question. In such a situation, would it be better to get two tickets through an airline (with no connection protection) or through a 3rd party (with weak connection protection)? I guess your recommendation is the former.

@HanMah. I think you have a false premise here.  If a  3rd party offers this as a single ticket, than some airline will as well.  If the only thing the 3rd party offers is a self connection, they are NOT adding any value at all and you are better off buying your separate tickets yourself directly from the airline.  It would be helpful to share what exactly you saw on trip.com: single ticker or self connection.

@Hilmar , wow, it's worse than I realized. Those are individual tickets, each with their own baggage policy. I guess the recommendation to avoid OTA still holds in this case.

Another thing to consider is that some airlines (used to, at least) allow flights from SRC to DST with a layover of a few days in MID, if MID is their base airport. That was true for AirFrance and CDG (Paris). You could book a single ticket from SRC --> CDG and 2 days later CDG --> DST. Another US carrier (United, perhaps? I'm not sure) did that too. I knew someone who took a flight Sao Paulo --> New York (for 2 days) --> Paris in a single ticket.

I think the recommendation is to avoid 3rd party booking services unless you're willing to accept some element of risk (and there's a genuine benefit, not just a marginal price saving). If there's a significant price difference and you've allowed plentiful margins and have some chance of making alternative arrangements, then it can be worth using a reputable service. If you're not confident or don't have cash reserves, then avoiding them is good advice. But as mentioned, shop around, try partner airlines (who often have different deals on the same routes), etc.

The fact that the two airports are not served by a single common airline does not mean you cannot book flights from one to the other from one of those airlines.
Most airlines have various forms of partnerships (interlining agreements, code shares, alliances...) which allow them to sell itineraries which include flights from many other airlines.
It does not necessarily mean that you can get any combination of flights/airlines, but it increases the possibilities quite a lot. The most notable exceptions are low-cost carriers, who very often don't even sell connections between their own flights, much less to/from other airlines.
You can start by looking for flights on Google Flights or any other flight search engine, they will tell you possible combinations.
For instance getting from Paramaribo in Suriname to Ko Samui in Thailand can be done like this:

As you can see, it involves 3 flights from 2 different airlines (and takes quite a while), but it's a single ticket.
Note that some engines will only show such combinations, while others (like Google Flights, Kiwi, and a few others) will show both these AND those involving a self-transfer, but will usually flag them as such. See below about that.
If you book via a third party, two situations may arise:

The itinerary can be bought as a single ticket directly from one of the airlines.
The itinerary cannot be bought as a single ticket, and they just go ahead and buy separate tickets for you, possibly including some vague promise that they will help you if this go awry, which often turns out to not quite work out.

In neither case does the OTA actually bring much value (other than possibly highlighting the existence of a combination).
So book directly with the airline(s). Note that sometimes, you cannot book the itinerary online directly with either airline, you will need to call them. The OTA may bring additional flexibility at this stage (letting you book online directly), but the drawbacks later on if issues arise and they start playing ping-pong are real. It's already complex enough with 2 or more airlines involved, it's a nightmare when you add an unmotivated OTA on top. It's up to you to determine which is more important to you.
If they are able to sell the whole itinerary on a single ticket, you are protected: if you miss the connection, or if they change the schedule or cancel either flight, they have to make it right (though the procedures and protections may vary depending on the countries involved).
If it's not possible to book the whole itinerary as a single ticket, and you book them separately (a so-called "self-transfer"), remember that there are lots of possible additional issues:

If you miss a connection, you are on your own (onward ticket may be cancelled, including subsequent flights on the same ticket, like a return flight, and you need to find and pay for a new flight out of your own pocket
If they change the schedules or cancel a flight and the new schedules no longer work together (first flight arriving after the second flight leaves...), you are on your own
You may need more visas if you transit in a country which requires one
Baggage allowances may not align
Even if everything goes well, you need more time for the connection, especially if you have hold luggage, as you need to wait for your bags, and you need to check-in for the next flight before the check-in deadline (often around one hour before scheduled departure)
You may have to spend time going through passport control and/or security which may not be needed in other circumstances

Self-transfers are best for seasoned travellers, and require careful consideration of the risks involved (Can you book a new flight timely and cheaply, even at the last minute, if you miss the original one? Can you afford the extra costs?). Having several hours between the flights is strongly recommended, ideally even an overnight stay.
Note that even when the whole itinerary is booked as a single ticket, you may want to stop in intermediate cities (because you want to break up a very long trip, or because you want to visit said city). This is still possible with the "multi-city" option available on most booking engines. Note that depending on the policies of the airlines involved, it may cost more than a direct connection.
To take your initial example, I see the following cases:

I want to get from SRC to DST and I don't care about MID, and I can book the SRC-MID-DST directly from the airline as one ticket -> buy that
I want to get from SRC to DST and I would like to stop in MID for a few days (in both directions): I'll check the options of buying SRC-MID-DST with stopovers and SRC-MID + MID-DST (both directly from the airline(s)) and buy the cheapest
I want to get from SRC to DST and I don't care about MID, but I can't book the SRC-MID-DST directly from the airline as one ticket -> I'll first look for other alternatives. If none are convenient, I'll buy SRC-MID and MID-DST separately, directly from the airline(s), but I'll have a lot of buffer in between (how much depends on the exact flights, including their frequency, duration and cost).

Remember: very long delays are relatively rare, but they DO happen.
Also don't forget to take travel insurance, and read the fine print to know what they covert or don't cover, in what circumstances.

Thanks! Option 1 exists, but it's so unreasonably expensive, I'm not sure why they would even list it (it would be cheaper to buy 4 last minute 1 way tickets). You did confirm my concerns regarding OTA. If I take the risk of option 3, it is still is better than OTA. Although thanks for the suggestion regarding travel insurance. I assume that there are some that I could find that would cover me if the flight has been altered enough. I'll have to check the fine print.

It really depends on the ticketing agent -- basically the Amadeus system is a piece of really arcane technology that is difficult to use, but gives full flexibility in booking, while airline websites go for simplicity and will not even present you simple options like "extend this layover by 24 hours, but keep all the flights on a single ticket." So a skilled agent can definitely get you tickets that are not available online. Airlines use Amadeus even to sell their own tickets, so airline agents have access to the same ticketing options, but often it is a skill issue.
